# Predis: Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Tags: laravel, redis, forge, predis

I've been trying to deploy a `Laravel` application using `Forge` for a while now, but I always get stuck on `Predis` giving me the following error:

> Predis\Connection\ConnectionException
>   Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

And everywhere I look the fix appears to be `read_write_timeout` to `-1` or `0` in `config/database.php`, however this doesn't fix the issue for me. I've cleared all caches (manually and via Artisan) but the error remains.

So basically whatever fix I try and apply, the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same issue and resolved it by adding the following line to the database.php file of the Laravel project:

```php
'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tls')
```

The final Redis configuration is as follows:

```php
'default' => ($url = env('REDIS_URL'))
    ? [ // Production configuration
        'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tls'),
        'host' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST),
        'password' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS),
        'port' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT),
        'database' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),
        'read_write_timeout' => -1,
    ]
    : [ // Original local configuration
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Kaspersky installed, disable `Network Attack Blocker` will fix it.

I've tried both Predis and PhpRedis but still error:
`read error on connection to 127.0.0.1:6379` or `Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`

The only way is disable Network Attack Blocker (Kaspersky doesn't even show any events in report, but it blocks redis somehow)

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if **Redis** is installed on your server ?

Comment: I should've mentioned this, sorry. But yes, Redis is installed

Comment: To clarify, I've tested by executing both "redis-server --version" and "redis-cli ping" and both return excepted responses.